# Wordpress convert url query string to slash and mask single path using htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Can anyone please help me understand if there is any standard function or process in wordpress that can be used to convert dynamic query strings to static just like how wordpress converts dynamic url

for example my url is generated as

```
http://example.com/payment/?username=nijesh
```

I want it to be converted as below

```
http://example.com/nijesh
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [template_include filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include).  You can access the global `$wp_query` variable and return the appropriate template based on your query string.